# Get ajax value from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not an JS developer, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I have this web application, that uses ajax to keep the data update on the screen, but I'm not able to use the ajax value in my JS function, the code generated by my application is:

```
<span id="c0"></span>
```

In the web page I just see the numeric value, e.g. 5 and it's updated every second as expected, so I tried to use the same in my JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPoint()
{
    console.log ('<span id="c0"></span>');
    return 0;
}
</script>
```

But in the Chrome's log I just see `<span id="c0"></span>` instead of a numeric value.

Comment: you should post a bit more of your code.

Comment: that is because in your getPoint function you are just logging '<span id="c0"></span>' - it is static. The span element you posted doesn't even have a number in it so we can't be sure that is even the right element. As @tuga mentioned, we need more code to actually help you.

Comment: Console.log will only return whatever is specified within it.So it's doing as specified. Try console.log($('#c0').text())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console.log simply logs whatever string you send it as a parameter. So what you are seeing is the expected behavior.

Assuming you are using jQuery, and the ajax returned value is being displayed in the span (id = "c0"), this console.log statement should work:

```
console.log($("#c0").text());
```

$("#c0") returns the jQuery object using the id selector (#).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPoint()
{
    var span_element = document.getElementById("c0");
    var content = span_element.innerHTML;
    console.log(content);
    return content;
}
</script>
```

**Explanation**:

First you need to access the DOM element of javascript. You identified the element with the id: "c0". To access the element you need to use the function: document.getElementById("someID");

With the element you can do a lot of things. In this case you want to access whatever is inside the tag , so what you want is its inner HTML.

If you are using JQuery, you can also get its content like this:

```
var span_element = $("#c0");
var content = span_element.text();
```